# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Error on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, error-handling, view, controller

0

I reached a part I cannot figure out. When trying to display a product on home page I get the following error:

`Undefined variable: products (View: /home/acer/test/project_basket/basket/resources/views/home.blade.php)`

For me is the first project in php and i'm not very practice in this language.

home.blade.php:

```
@section('content')
<div class="card-deck">


/*Problem Here */
  @foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="card">
    <img src="{{ $product->imagePath }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title }}</h5>
       <p class="color">{{ $product->color }}</p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Buy Now</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add to Cart</button>
    <div class="price">${{ $product->price }}/div>
  </div>
 </div>
@endsection
```

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['imagePath', 'title', 'price', 'color'];
}
```

ProductController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller

{
    /**
    *@return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::inRandomorder()->take(6)->get();
        return view('home')->with('products', $products);
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
//Route::view('/`home`', 'home');


Route::get('/', 'ProductController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('welcome');

//Route::get('/home', 'DasboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: *not so practice

Comment: with which url are you getting this error? `/home`?

Comment: yes is `/home` url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hare "hitting" the `/home` endpoint, which looking at your route is pointing to `ProfilesController`, but you are working on `ProductController` so have written the wrong Controller in `web.php`